# Dynamic sum function

Tags: excel, function, dynamic, sum

I'm working on a spreadsheet where I would like to be able to sum a certain number of cells automatically. E.g. I put in 120 or 100 in my reference cell and Excel then gives me the sum of the top 120 or 100 cells in my revenue column. Is there a way to do this? I've thought about simply naming the range of cells like "top120revenue" and "top100revenue" etc. but besides being static it is also complicated when working with 27 sheets. If a formula exists it would be easier to simply change the sheet reference instead of relabeling the range of cells. Maybe the answer lies in VBA but I'm by no means an expert there

Hope someone can help!?

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean the top n cells **positionally** or the n highest values? If it's the former I would use INDEX which is a little more robust than INDIRECT i.e.

`=SUM(A1:INDEX(A:A,B1))`

If you mean the n largest values then try

`=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(A:A,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&B1))))`

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer to your question [here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-new-users-basics/765372-use-cell-value-in-a-cell-reference.html). It uses the function `INDIRECT()`.

For example: if column `A` holds your data and `B1` is your reference cell containing the value `100`, then the formule below gives the sum of the first 100 values of column `A`.

```
=SUM(A1:INDIRECT("A"&B1))
```

This gets interpreted as:

```
=SUM(A1:A100)
```